# PHP Сохранение состояния

Tags: php

Интересует вопрос про сохранение состояния:

Допустим у нас есть простая логика игры BlackJack (21) против компьютера на сервере (php). Логика замешивания, раздачи карт и тд и тп.

Тут возникает вопрос, какие есть способы сохранения состояния конкретной игры для пользователя? Например инициализировали колоду и выдали первые карты пользователю, тут он решает добрать или же вскрыться как есть... За интерфейс отвечает JS (отправляет запросы на сервер).

Из-за ожидания и возможности разнообразных действий пользователя требуется сохранения состояния игры (возможно я ошибаюсь). И на ум приходит только сессия или же БД (хотя я даже ещё не осмыслил всю логику).

Правильное ли это решение? Есть ли другие решения?

Comment: Можно ещё писать в файл.

Answer (score 0):

Можно, как вариант, состояние хранить на стороне клиента, в локальном Storage объекте броузера [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

При подключении клиента к серверу, он должен сохраненную сессию(если она есть) подтвердить у сервера. Если сессия подтверждена, то она используется дальше. Если не подтверждена - пересоздается заново.